# productFlavor buildConfigField produces duplicate entries in BuildConfig.java

Tags: android

I have set a buildConfigField in the build.gradle:

```
android {
productFlavors {
    pro {
        buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'FLAVOR', '"pro"'
        applicationId "my.app.pro"
    }
    free {
        buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOR', '"free"'
    }
}

}
```

When I try to build a signed apk this fails, because Build.Config.java contains two entries of *FLAVOR*:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "my.app.pro";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "pro";
  // Fields from product flavor: pro
  public static final Boolean FLAVOR = "pro";
}
```

I used buildToolsVersion 24.0.0 rc3 and tried 23.0.0 with the same result.
Why is there a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio already adds a `FLAVOR` field to `BuildConfig` for projects with flavors.

Either:

- Use the one that Android Studio already adds, or
- Rename yours to something other than `FLAVOR`